# Use cherry-pick or merge to get the changes of a bugfix into two branches?

Tags: git, azure-devops

We are using Azure DevOps and have a `develop` and several `release` branches.

In our latest `release` branch we needed to fix an issue. So we branched off into a `hotfix` branch. Fixed everything and merged back via pull request (squash commits).

Now we want to include this fix also in `develop`. 
From my understanding, since I only want this one commit, I'd cherry-pick the `hotfix` branch into `develop`.

So far this works fine.

But I am now confused. When I display the diffs (ahead/behind) between `develop` and `release` branch it shows the `release` is ahead. But all the ahead files were already cherry-picked into `develop`.

This makes keeping track of which hotfixes were already cherry-picked into `develop` hard.

So what's the correct way?

Comment: So practically you have two branches (`develop`, `release`), completely similar, as you have just checked out `r` from `d`. Than you have practically added one single commit to `r` (the squashed merge) and cherry-picked it to `d`. In deed, it should not have any difference.

Comment: Also when I list the ahead files, it shows the exact files and their contents that are already in develop.

Comment: I recommend reading *all* of the articles gathered under this page: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180323-01/?p=98325

Answer (score 0):

Stop doing squash merges and cherry picks until you know what you're doing.  You chose not to record your merges (cherry-pick is also a merge, of just that one commit's changes).  Now they're merged to multiple places without any record of those merges.  Sometimes that's what you want. It wasn't what you wanted here.

> So what's the correct way?

`git merge`.

From comments, when you did the

> So we branched off into a hotfix branch. Fixed everything and merged back via pull request (squash commits).

you branched off unmerged history rather than off a common base.  I personally like using the commit that introduced a bug as the hotfix base and merging from there, but that's a distinctly minority preference.  If you've got multiple working tips, the most-recent base to work off of, mergeable to all of them, is their merge base.  *This* is what cherry-pick is for: you've already based the fix on an unmerged branch made for other purposes. So `git branch hotfixes $(git merge-base release develop feature2 whateverelse); git checkout hotfixes; git cherry-pick yourhotfix`.  Then merge that.

Comment: But using git merge I'd get all the changs made to release branch that I don't want in develop

Answer (score 0):

@jthill is right, a squash merge takes all the file changes and adds them to a single new commit on the default branch. I made a test based on your description. We can see the commits of release and develop are as below:

[image]

[image]

No matter what merge method you use, it will always generate a new commit in develop. This is inevitable.

[image]

Comment: And that's also exactly what we want. I mean everything works fine except it shows the wrong "ahead".

Comment: The circle in your picture shows in my repository 2 ahead, even though the files are the same when using diff. This is duo to using cherry-pick after a pull request.

Comment: How do you merage your cherry-pick to your develop branch? If use the normal merage, it will have 2 ahead, but if you use squash commits, it will have only one ahead.